ERROR org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Creating maps using application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not allowed
After installing tiling vectortiles plugin to geoserver .2.25 we have got an error
08 Apr 15:29:48 ERROR  [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Problem communicating with GeoServer http://geo.server.local/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/someXXX:regioonSX_mapping@EPSG:900913@pbf/18/152590/173718.pbf 08 Apr 15:29:48 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Creating maps using application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not allowed
and like
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Creating maps using application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not allowed 08 Apr 15:03:14 ERROR  [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Problem communicating with GeoServer http://geo.server.local/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/someXXX:regioonSX_mapping@EPSG:900913@pbf/18/152590/173718.pbf 08 Apr 15:03:14 ERROR  [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
According to plugin installation we did all necessary things.
Expected binary file 173718.pbf
Documentation to VectorTiles:
https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html
In a result the problem was here

scroll down and look for "Allowed MIME types for a GetMap request"

Do not forget about new restrictions here in

